# Error javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In console, I have this error. I use the latest jquery 3.1.

How to rectify this element ?

Thank you

typeError: window.on is not a function

```
<script>(window).on('load', function (){var maxHeight=0;$(".equal-height").each(function(){if($(this).height()>maxHeight){maxHeight=$(this).height();}});$(".equal-height").height(maxHeight);});</script>
```

Comment: You missed `$` at the beginning.

Comment: Change (window) to $(window)

Comment: Have you used jQuery before?

Comment: Anyone else for a downvote?!? It seems to be great fun to kick the ones being beaten already ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$` as a prefix to the `(window)` part of your script or it won't be a JQuery object.

```
<script>$(window).on('load', function (){var maxHeight=0;$(".equal-height").each(function(){if($(this).height()>maxHeight){maxHeight=$(this).height();}});$(".equal-height").height(maxHeight);});</script>
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `$(function(){... });` will do the same.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the `$` symbol at the start of your code, this is the shorthand for `jQuery` and needs to be used when using any of the jQuery library. Your complete code becomes:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".equal-height").each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $(".equal-height").height(maxHeight);
};
```

This is also the same as

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".equal-height").each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $(".equal-height").height(maxHeight);
};
```